Why the global default@color settings doen't work with xcoffins?
As the link globally-set-the-text-color, showing the following method to change the color globally:
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\globalcolor}[1]{%
  \color{#1}\global\let\default@color\current@color
}
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{\globalcolor{red}}

However, when I use the tasks package, and I found that the item didn't change the defaultcolor? As I immersed in the original code, I also found that the xcoffins also doesn't work with the proper color change?
My Question is that:

Why the l3coffin didn't typeset the matrials with \default@color such a bottom macro?

What's the BEST practice to change ALL the case(EVERYWHERE) in the documents?

Is there exists some other environments that didn't use the \default@color,how to prevent the case of xcoffins here from happening again? Or whether we can change the color in the process of the engines rendering the PDF?

The final target to global change the document color is to reverse the color(shift the daymode to the nightmode), for the normally white background and black text, I want to change them into black background and white text, I wonder is there more elegant or convenient method to achieve that?


Here below is the MWE of the xcoffins
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tasks,xcolor,xcoffins}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\globalcolor}[1]{%
  \color{#1}\global\let\default@color\current@color
}
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{\globalcolor{red}}

\begin{document}

\section{A section heading}

some test text

\begin{tasks}
    \task item1
    \task item2
\end{tasks}

\begin{itemize}
    \item item1
    \item item2
\end{itemize}

\NewCoffin\MyCoffin
\SetHorizontalCoffin\MyCoffin{Explorer}
\TypesetCoffin\MyCoffin

\end{document}



Well colors are currently hard, as they are three packages around: color, xcolor, l3color (part of the kernel).  Your color command handles the first two, but you need to handle also l3color.
If you set the new normalcolor in the preamble there is no need to map internal commands, simply selecting the colors is enough:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tasks,xcoffins}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\color{red}
\color_select:n{red}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{A section heading}

some test text

\begin{tasks}
    \task item1
    \task item2
\end{tasks}

\begin{itemize}
    \item item1
    \item item2
\end{itemize}

\NewCoffin\MyCoffin
\SetHorizontalCoffin\MyCoffin{Explorer}
\TypesetCoffin\MyCoffin

\normalcolor blub
\end{document} 



I also wonder the relationship between the color, xcolor and l3color, what kinds of command's text color is handled by each of them respectively?

What's more, as for my question 4, is their better method to switch the day-mode to dark-mode? Thanks to yr kindness solution!

I found that this method is not really very fundamentally: the text color in fancyhdr has not changed at all.

@Skyrmion Do not ping only me, ask a new question with an example.
